# XSD validation rule for assertion

Tags: xml, validation, xpath, xsd

I am working off a XSD where I need to Validate 2 elements under same complex type using assertion.

There are two elements OpenDate and CloseDate. I am using the rule

```
<xs:assert test="if(  
    xs:date(concat(
            substring( OpenDate ,7 ,4 ) ,
            '-',
            substring( OpenDate ,1,2 ),
            '-', 
            substring( OpenDate ,4 ,2 ))  )
    &lt; xs:date(concat(
            substring( ClosedDate,7,4),
            '-',
            substring( ClosedDate,1,2),
            '-',
            substring( ClosedDate,4,2)))) 
    then true() 
    else false()" 
    saxon:message="close date cannot be a date before membership open date"/>
```

But this would generate error report at record level. The Xpath is shown as Root/Record. Also It Would not display Element it error-ed out on. I Would Need report to Have xpath as Root/Record/OpenDate and Element name displayed rather than just Record.

Also, can you Suggest is there a way to call sibling element using Assertion in the element. like

```
<xs:element name="OpenDate" 
            type="CMGDateFormat" 
            minOccurs="0" 
            maxOccurs="1">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <format>AAAAAAA</format>
      <originalName><![CDATA[MembershipOpenDate]]></originalName>
      <parent> </parent>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="MembershipClosedDate" 
            minOccurs="0" 
            maxOccurs="1">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <format>AAAAAAA</format>
      <originalName><![CDATA[MembershipClosedDate]]></originalName>
      <parent> </parent>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="CMGDateFormat">
      <xs:assertion test="
        if(  xs:date(concat(  
               substring( $value,7 ,4 ) ,
               '-',
               substring( $value,1,2 ),
               '-', 
               substring( $value,4 ,2 ))  ) 
             &lt; 
             xs:date(concat(
               substring( Root/Record/Opendate,7,4),
               '-',
               substring( Root/Record/Opendate,1,2),
               '-',
               substring( Root/Record/Opendate,4,2)))) 
        then true() 
        else false()" 
      saxon:message="close date cannot be a date before membership open date"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve the above. I want to use assertion to validate two different elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSD 1.1 assertions are designed to be evaluatable without reference to context:  when an element E is being validated against a declaration D containing an assertion A, then E is (conceptually, at least) copied into a new document containing E and nothing else, and then assertion A is evaluated against the root element of that temporary document (i.e. the copy of E).  It is not an error for A to contain subexpressions which in the original context would refer to elements outside E, but in the context created for evaluating A, those subexpressions will evaluate to the empty sequence.

Note that your example contains references to `Root/Record/Opendate`, which does not in any case denote a sibling element.  (You may have meant `../Opendate`.)

If your problem is that your error message does not provide enough detail, you may want to look into ways to make it more informative.